# Select Statement Ratio Calculation Not Working as Expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that will give me a ratio calculation based on certain counts from two columns which are working however unless there is data in the table, it won't be able to calculate a ratio.

To mitigate this I want my script to convert all `null` values to a `1`.

This is my current script (I'm removing the rest of the joins because it isn't necessary to include)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TB1.Person,
TB2.AllocatedCount as AllocatedCount,
TB3.UnallocatedCount as UnallocatedCount,
AllocatedCount * 1.0 / UnallocatedCount * 1.0 as Ratio,
```

The above yields the following results which work perfectly provided the table has data for both columns:

| Person | AllocatedCount | UnallocatedCount | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1.0000000000000 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 2.0000000000000 |
| C | null | null | null |

I want to change the script so that all null results would represent the number `1` however the ratio doesnt seem to be calculating.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TB1.Person,
CASE WHEN TB2.AllocatedCount IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE TB2.AllocatedCount as AllocatedCount,
CASE WHEN TB3.UnallocatedCount IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE TB3.UnallocatedCount as UnallocatedCount,
AllocatedCount * 1.0 / UnallocatedCount * 1.0 as Ratio,
```

Above yields the following results:

| Person | AllocatedCount | UnallocatedCount | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1.0000000000000 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 2.0000000000000 |
| C | 1 | 1 | null |

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with my script to not calculate the ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to check for `NULL` values when you calculate the ratio (using `ISNULL()` here is probably a better option):

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT TB1.Person,
   ISNULL(TB2.AllocatedCount, 1) AS AllocatedCount,
   ISNULL(TB3.UnallocatedCount, 1) AS UnallocatedCount,
   ISNULL(TB2.AllocatedCount, 1) * 1.0 / ISNULL(TB3.UnallocatedCount, 1) * 1.0 AS Ratio
FROM 
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TB1.Person,
isnull(TB2.AllocatedCount,1) as AllocatedCount,
isnull(TB3.UnallocatedCount,1) as UnallocatedCount,
isnull(AllocatedCount,1) * 1.0 / isnull(UnallocatedCount,1) * 1.0 as Ratio,
```